# Issue with subqueries and UNION on MariaDB - is this a bug?

Tags: mysql, database, union, mariadb

I'm interested in determining if this strange behavior I encountered in MariaDB is a bug:

I created a view, comprising the following code, which UNIONs the output of two tables containing similar data together. Each table contains multiple years, and state_incometax_deductions contains data for multiple states, for multiple years. The goal of the view is to get the latest row of data available for each state:

```
(
    SELECT "Federal" AS StateName, 
        Year,Data1,Data2
    FROM federal_incometax_deductions
    WHERE ( Year = (SELECT Max(Year) FROM federal_incometax_deductions) )
)
UNION
(
    SELECT  StateName,Year,Data1,Data2
    FROM state_incometax_deductions x
    WHERE Year = (
      SELECT Max(Year) 
      FROM state_incometax_deductions 
      WHERE StateName=x.StateName # <-- This is the important part
    )
    ORDER BY StateName DESC
);
```

This code successfully yielded the latest row of data available for each state as expected when I ran on my development server (MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.17).

However, when I run on production (mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.47-MariaDB), I consistently get ONLY the results from table 1 (federal_incometax_deductions), and nothing from table 2.

When running, I also get a few warnings which don't seem relevant to my query at all: `Incorrect datetime value: '2016'`. These warnings disappear if I switch to UNION ALL, but the query still doesn't return the expected data.

When I run the second query on its own outside of the UNION, it works. When I remove the `WHERE StateName=x.StateName` from inside the union, it also starts working. This implies that the issue is caused by the WHERE referencing an alias of the table being queried.

I finally found out that I could get this working by replacing the `Year =` with a `Year IN`, which for some reason works fine and returns the expected results.

I can't find any explanation for this behavior, though it appears that MariaDB made some changes to their handling of UNIONs in the version I'm running.

Is this a bug in MariaDB?

Comment: What does your data look like?  Are there any states whose max year is not the max year in the entire `federal_incometax_deductions` table?

Comment: Probably not a bug.Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with a desired result

Comment: Please file a bug with MariaDB.

Comment: Can you post the `EXPLAIN` for each case (including `YEAR =`, etc.)

Comment: @Tim, yes, there are - though most states have a max year the same as federal max year, some are lower. Will post explain and create statements soon.

This smells alot like a bug to me, given that the exact query works in other versions, the components work individually, and I made it work by doing something as odd as changing = to IN